Leakage Current Test Setup
I'm working on designing an intermediary board to evaluate the performance of several different leakage current measurement methods including two different magnetometers, a specialized current transformer, and a standard current transformer.
This board will be placed in-line with the power input for a power switching device. I need to develop some sort of test apparatus that can accurately and repeatedly cause leakage currents of between 1 and 100 mA for single-phase 120 V AC power with a load of up to 10 A.
One solution that was mentioned to me was using a decade box and an external meter to swap in different resistor shunts. Does anyone have experience with similar systems or have any tips on making such a test setup?
